# How can I embed GeoJSON in markdown on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, geojson, github-flavored-markdown

Their toy example at [docs.github.com](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-diagrams#creating-geojson-and-topojson-maps) is broken:

```
{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
      [
          [-90,30],
          [-90,35],
          [-90,35],
          [-85,35],
          [-85,30]
      ]
  ]
}
```

It doesn't render as promised, and it doesn't even pass a [linter](https://geojsonlint.com).

I've created a smallish [reprex](https://github.com/dholstius/GH-geojson) to show that fixing the linter issues doesn't make it work. GitHub then complains "We can't render a map with an empty unknown collection." Fixing that doesn't seem to help either. But maybe I'm making a mistake.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "properties": {
        "ID": 0
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
              [-90,35],
              [-90,30],
              [-85,30],
              [-85,35],
              [-90,35]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```